# Pin this program to taskbar option missing in my C# application

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskbar

All programs I have tried so far in Windows 7 have a 'Pin this program to taskbar' item when right-clicking them in the task bar.
I have a C# program that only shows 'Close Window' and nothing else. It is build with C# 2010 Express, and targets .NET 3.5 framework.

I can't find any reason why no other options show up or any properties I could change.
Does anyone know what property could affect this option?

Answer (score 24):

There could be one of a few reasons for this:

- Executables located on remote locations (i.e. a server share) cannot be pinned; only local executables can be pinned
- Certain strings in the shortcut or executable name cause that program to be excluded from pinning. These restricted values are determined by a registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\AddRemoveNames` and has these default values: `Documentation;Help;Install;More Info;Readme;Read me;Read First;Setup;Support;What's New;Remove`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the executable is local, and the name is 'SkinHelper.exe'. Even trying different names did not help. It is also not limited to my computer only, other people who installed it are seeing the same thing.

Comment: @Adion, The answer says that if your app includes the word Help in its name, it won't pin. And you reploy "Yeah, it's called SkinHelper.exe so that's not it." Huh? What's more, it tells you how to change the registry so your app can pin.

Comment: I see now that this answer also had the solution, but I misread the part that says the filename can also not contain any of these strings. The different names I tried probably still included 'help'...

Answer (score 4):

this also has something to do with the location of your EXE as well. my problem was that my EXE was being run from a network location. if i moved it to the local drive then all was right with the world.

Answer (score 2):

This can sometimes be caused by a "feature" in Windows 7, some filenames are reserved and dont get taskbar status in Windows7, try renaming your .exe file to something else also could you post the name of your .exe?

And if you dont want to rename the file if you browse using the registry to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\AddRemoveNames

You will see a delimited string with the reserved names.

Answer (score 1):

Check your registry for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\[exe name] .  Remove that key and you should have the pinning options again (without logging out or restarting too!)

In my scenario, my installer file (created by InstallAware) has the same name as the program launcher exe.  I am guessing that when I run the installer the installer exe name gets added to that registry location so you can't use the pinning options.  I changed my installer file output name with InstallAware and that solved the issue.  It is not enough to do a simple rename.

Answer (score 1):

For exe. files only
With a problem like this the easy way is to;
1. Open properties of program
2. Open file location
3. Rename file (first copying name just in case)
4. Then right click on file and pin to taskbar should be there
5. If this doesn't work try another name

If this fails you can always rename the exe. to its original

This as always worked for me